# Html button is not coming up with alert message from case function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use case statements to give me three different alerts for three different button presses

I have tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function something(){
 var counter = 0;
var button = document.querySelector("#button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
counter++;
switch(counter) {
    case 1:
        alert("something");
        break;
    case 2:
        alert("something else");
        break;
    case 3:
        alert("something else else");
        break;
  }
 });
 }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="button" value="enter" type="button">
</body>
</html>
```

There are no errors in the console. The button is showing up on the webpage but not the alerts.

Comment: where is `something` function being called? javascript doesn't "know" when you want to call that function

Comment: I just made an onclick="something" in the input tag and it still will not work

Comment: `onclick="something"` - no you didn't ... and if you did, you should make it `onclick="something()"` so it gets executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jaromanda points out, you need to invoke the function as well as defining it, like:

```js
function something() {
  var counter = 0;
  var button = document.querySelector("#button");

  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    counter++;
    switch (counter) {
      case 1:
        alert("something");
        break;
      case 2:
        alert("something else");
        break;
      case 3:
        alert("something else else");
        break;
    }
  });
}
something();
```

```html
<input id="button" value="enter" type="button">
```

Alternatively, it might be more intuitive to set up the code this way, identifying the button and the counter variable outside of the function, then incrementing the counter each time the function is called (inside the function.)

(Note: This version includes two additional features:

1) The `if` statement resets the counter to zero if it gets too high, so every click results in an alert. Just remove this statement (or comment it out) if you prefer for clicks beyond the third to do nothing.

2) There's a `default` case in the switch statement -- in case something went wrong and our code gave an unexpected value to the counter, this would help us debug that problem.)

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#button");
let counter = 0;
button.addEventListener("click", doAlert);

function doAlert(){
  if (counter == 3){ counter = 0; }
  counter++;
  switch (counter) {
    case 1: alert("something"); break;
    case 2: alert("something else"); break;
    case 3: alert("something else else"); break;
    default: alert("this should be impossible"); break;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="button" value="Enter" type="button">
```